# EF Core specify DB Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

hopefully a quick one for you guys. I´m looking for solution on how to specify the DBName during a code first approach with EF Core. At the moment, all my tables are created in the "master" database, but I would like to create a dedicated DB obviously for my project.

Here is my code:
Startup.cs

```
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<SADbContext>(
                options => SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(options, config.GetConnectionString("SqlConnectionString"))
            );
```

I do also have the DB Context:

```
    public class SADbContext : DbContext
    { 
        public SADbContext(DbContextOptions<SADbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
 
        }
```

Would appreciate your help.

Best,
Chris

Comment: You need to explicit define a database in your connection string (that you are not sharing)

Comment: ok, will check it

Comment: `all my tables are created in the "master"` that a very bad idea. `master` is only meant for server-side system tables and data, not application data. Applications rarely need access to `master`

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicit define a database in your connection string

```
 Database=mydatabase;Server=myserver
```